DbScan from sklearn vs Dbscan from Rapids
I'm trying out the Rapids version of DbScan that works with GPUs.
I wrote a short code in Python that finds clusters in 3D random generated points, and when I was playing with the code, I realized that the CPU is way faster than the GPU for some reason that I am not familiar with:
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from cuml.cluster import DBSCAN as cuDBSCAN
import cupy as cp

pij_gpu = cp.asarray(pij.astype(np.float32))  # Transfer data to GPU
eps = 0.3
min_samples = 5
start = time.time()
cluster = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples, n_jobs=-1)
cluster.fit(pij)
print(f"CPU: {time.time() - start}")

start = time.time()
cluster_gpu = cuDBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples)
cluster_gpu.fit(pij_gpu)
print(f"GPU: {time.time() - start}")

the logs:
size is: (670761, 3)
CPU: 1.508012294769287
[W] [14:24:17.089902] Batch size limited by the chosen integer type (4 bytes). 6007 -> 3201. Using the larger integer type might result in better performance
GPU: 10.168060541152954

I printed pij size.
Am I missing something?
I've looked around the internet and used ChatGPT to find an answer, but I couldn't find one answer.
One thing that I was noticing is that when the points are closer, the GPU tends to go a bit faster than the CPU.
I have nvidia 3090 and a relatively strong pc.
